# работа с Git из-под системной учетной записи (windows)

Tags: windows, git

Есть приложение которое выполняет всякие гитовые команды, раньше оно работало в моем РДП сеансе, все было нормально, потом сделал что б приложение работало как служба, служба работает под системной учеткой, теперь приложение не может выполнять команды гита, в логах ошибка "Authentication failed". Что куда прописать? В глобальном конфиге гита задан name и email.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: логично, потому что с под сеанса сервиса Ваши креды не доступны.

Comment: сделать то что?

Comment: прочитать внимательно это https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage  потом понять, как именно у Вас сохранились креды и прописать их так, что бы сервис их видел.

Comment: ясно, помощник из тебя так себе